# In Scrapy, why is text()[n] in an Xpath expression followed by extract() not equivalent to extract() followed by selecting the [n-1]th element?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to scrapy APK download pages from http://www.apkmirror.com, but some of my XPath expressions are not acting as I would expect.

For example, in the Scrapy shell for http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/maps/maps-9-2-0-9-release/maps-9-2-0-android-4-3-902013124-android-apk-download/, I extract the 'APK details' section as follows:

```
In [1]: response.xpath('//*[@title="APK details"]/following-sibling::*[@class="appspec-value"]//text()').extract()
Out[1]: 
[u'Version: 9.2.0 (902013124)',
 u'arm ',
 u'Package: com.google.android.apps.maps',
 u'\n',
 u'40,353 downloads ']
```

I want to extract the supported architectures, which is this case is `'arm '` on the second line. I extract the line by

```
In [2]: response.xpath('//*[@title="APK details"]/following-sibling::*[@class="appspec-value"]//text()[2]').extract()
Out[2]: [u'arm ']
```

So far, so good, but there are other pages such as http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/htc-corporation/htc-backup/htc-backup-4-5-696121-release/htc-backup-4-5-696121-android-apk-download/ where the line containing the version is absent. In this case I get

```
In [3]: response.xpath('//*[@title="APK details"]/following-sibling::*[@class="appspec-value"]//text()').extract()
Out[3]: 
[u'Version: 4.5.696121 (454663465) ',
 u'Package: com.htc.backup',
 u'\n',
 u'1,664 downloads ']
```

The strange thing is that if I add a `[2]` after the preceding XPath expression, I get a blank line:

```
In [2]: response.xpath('//*[@title="APK details"]/following-sibling::*[@class="appspec-value"]//text()[2]').extract()
Out[2]: [u'\n']
```

This corresponds to the third element of the list obtained from the `extract()`, whereas I would expect it to still be the second line starting with `Package:`.

In short, it seems like my assumption that 'including `[n]` in the Xpath expression and calling `extract()` is equivalent to calling `extract()` and selecting `[n-1]` from the resulting list' is not correct. Can someone confirm this and explain why not?

Comment: What about `(//*[@title="APK details"]/following-sibling::*[@class="appspec-value"]//text())[2]`?

Comment: If I try `response.xpath('(//*[@title="APK details"]/following-sibling::*[@class="appspec-value"]//text‌​())[2]').extract()`, I get a `ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take this XML as an example:

```
<r>
  <p id="1">
    <c>text 1</c>
    <c>text 2</c>
    <c>text 3</c>
  </p>
  <p id="2">
    <c>text 4</c>
    <c>text 5</c>
    <c><a>text 6</a><a>text 7</a></c>
  </p>
</r>
```

`//c//text()[1]` returns `text 1 - 6`, as they all are *the first text below `c`*.

`//c//text()[2]` returns `text 7`, as it's the only *second text below `c`*.

`(//c//text())[2]` returns `text 2`, as its the *second of all texts that are below some `c`*.

Comment: In the original example, I noticed by removing the `//text()` from the XPath expression that the different list items in the `extract()` result arise from the self-closing `<br>` tag, which in itself doesn't contain `text()`.